# How to set up a service url with parameters using generic method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 200+ service URL. The URL's are in below format:

serviceURL = DomainName + MethodName + Path;

DomainName & MethodNames are configurable and path may be like below format:

```
Path = 'A' + '/' + Param1 + '/' + 'B' + '/' + Param2 + '/' + 'C'  + '/'+ Param3;
```

My requirement is to create a generic method where I can pass a single URL with parameters and that URL should set serviceURL accordingly. for e.g.

```
Var URL = 'domain1/method1/A/{0}/B/{1}/C/{2}';

GenericMethod(URL, Param1, Param2, Param3){

//in URL domain1 should get replaced by DomainName
// method1 should get replaced by MethodName
//path URL {0} {1} {2} get replaced by params

}
```

has anyone came across any such requirement/need?

open for suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question well, but if I did, than you can do something like this.

```
function getPath(URL, Param1, Param2, Param3){
    return URL.replace('{0}', Param1).replace('{1}', Param2).replace('{2}', Param3);
}

$http.get(getPath(URL, Param1, Param2, Param3));
```

It would be best to create a service with method that does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the `arguments` variable (available in every JS function) and a little bit of Regex:

```
function getServiceRequestURL(serviceURL) {

    var requestURL = serviceURL;

    for(var i = 1; i <= arguments.length; i++) {
        requestURL = requestURL.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + (i-1) + '\\}', 'gi'), arguments[i]);
    }

    return requestURL

}
```

What this does is get all arguments past the `serviceURL` and replace the `{0}` token with the actual parameter passed to the function. This will work for service URLs of any size, regardless of the amount of parameters given.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use regular expressions:

```
var urlScheme = '{domain}/{method}/A/{param1}/B/{param2}/C/{param3}';

var URL = GenericMethod(urlScheme, 'myDomain', 'doSomething', 'a', 'b', 'c');

function GenericMethod(scheme, domain, method, param1, param2, param3){    
    return url
        .replace(/\{domain\}/g, domain)
        .replace(/\{method\}/g, method)
        .replace(/\{param1\}/g, param1)
        .replace(/\{param2\}/g, param2)
        .replace(/\{param3\}/g, param3);
}
```

Or go even more generic by providing a hash of arguments instead of a list to GenericMethod ({ domain: 'myDomain', param1: 'myParam1'}) and then iterating over keys.

However, such a method will add an implicit dependency between otherwise independent services and some new service in future may require a different URL scheme, so in larger-scale apps URL schemes are usually not generalized beyond convention to prevent extra coupling.